# Setting up environmental variables in Mac OS X High Sierra 10.13.2 for spark/hadoop/java/python etc

Tags: environment-variables, macos-high-sierra

I would like to define environmental variables for Spark on Scala for using in terminal and/or IntelliJ.
What is the right way to set it up?
My hidden home elements are the following:

```
$ ls .
./                   .Trash/              .ivy2/
../                  .android/            .matplotlib/
.CFUserTextEncoding  .bash_history        .oracle_jre_usage/
.DS_Store            .bash_sessions/      .sbt/
```

Comment: IntelliJ uses its own path for Java, Python, defined as part of the Project SDKs. It does not reply on your environ variables. It should be similar to Scala setup.

Comment: Though I might use spark on shell so I will edit my question. Thanks for realising the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer as it can be done by editing(in not exist, creating) file in home directory as the following:

COMMAND

```
MacBook-Pro:~ User$ nano .bash_profile
```

TYPE

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home
export SCALA_HOME=/<SCALA-folder-path>
export HADOOP_HOME=/<HADOOP-folder-path>
export SPARK_HOME=/<Spark-folder-path>

PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$SCALA_HOME/bin:$SPARK_HOME/bin:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
export PATH
```